# how to resume download when app is not active or screen off condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I want to download one file from sever it come around 30/MB. 
`NSURLSessionDataTask` are the function I used for download.I want to know how to implement download a file when app in `background state` or when screen off.

Comment: Have you googled this? I tried `ios download file in the background` and came up with a lot of results that seemed very useful.

Comment: ok..will check thanks for comment

Comment: Also search in Xcode for "Using NSURLSession" and "Background Transfer Considerations". Finally, search in Xcode on "Simple Background Transfer", which should lead you to a sample project that shows how to do a background transfer. (The short version is that you need to create an NSURLSession that supports background transfers using `NSURLSession`'s `sessionWithConfiguration` method. You can create the session you use in the above call with the `NSURLSessionConfiguration` call `backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier`.)

Answer (score 0):

Add below in your      *- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application*

```
 UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
 UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;

 bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{ 
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask]; 
}];
```

This will work just fine.